# JssProvider in Material-UI isn't applying my custom production prefix to CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I've built a fairly simple React app based on [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) which uses the [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/) for its interface components. It also depends on one of my own packages which also uses Material-UI (same version) for a couple of shared components.

Things were looking good locally until I ran a production build and deployed it. Some of the styles were behaving oddly, for example the Material-UI grid was much narrower than when running locally.

I did some reading and found [a few instances of people](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/8223) discussing colliding class names under my scenario. This took me to some [official Material-UI documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#creategenerateclassname-options-class-name-generator) which provides the following example code to use a custom class name prefix:

```
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import { createGenerateClassName } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
  dangerouslyUseGlobalCSS: true,
  productionPrefix: 'c',
});

function App() {
  return (
    <JssProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
      ...
    </JssProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Before applying this fix when inspecting my production app's source code I could see the outermost `DIV` using the CSS class `jss2 jss24`.

*After* applying this fix my production app actually visually renders the same layout as my development version and so would appear to be fixed. However, examining the source shows the outermost `DIV` to have the class `MuiGrid-container-2 MuiGrid-spacing-xs-8-24` which suggests to me something isn't right. I could leave it like this but it does mean I'm running with unoptimised code.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is there an alternative resolution? I'm using current latest version of `@material-ui/core` (3.3.2) and the full contents of my `App.js` are:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { OidcProvider } from 'redux-oidc';
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import Routes from './routes';
import store from './store';
import userManager from './utils/userManager';
import { 
    CustomUiTheme as Theme, 
    CustomUiLayout as Layout,
    CustomUiSnackbar as Snackbar,
    CustomUiModalAlert as Alert
} from 'custom-ui';
import Loading from './components/loading';
import { createGenerateClassName } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
    dangerouslyUseGlobalCSS: true,
    productionPrefix: 'tw',
});

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <JssProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <OidcProvider store={store} userManager={userManager}>
                        <Theme>
                            <Loading />
                            <Layout variant="xmas">
                                <Alert />
                                <Routes />
                                <Snackbar />
                            </Layout> 
                        </Theme>
                    </OidcProvider>
                </Provider>
            </JssProvider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Have you tried placing JssProvider inside the Provider tag. Provider tag should wrap the JssProvider. I see nothing wrong with the code. is there any reason on why you are using dangerouslyUseGlobalCSS: true. I believe its not required.

Comment: This tweet might help you. You are doing the same. https://twitter.com/thevarunraja/status/1049754300656836613

Comment: Thank you. I moved `JssProvider` insider `Provider` and also removed the `dangerouslyUseGlobalCSS` line. This resolved the issue, although I'm afraid I'm not sure which of these actually fixed it. I'm pretty sure I originally had my `JssProvider` inside my `OidcProvider` and it was still not working. Anyway, I'm happy now!

Comment: Glad it helped.